# Copy files to another folder in a Windows Forms application

Tags: winforms, copy-paste

I want to copy some file from one folder to another folder of my PC using a context menu in a Windows Forms application. I know how to add a context menu, and I need to know the tricks to perform copy & paste. What type of control do I need to use?

Sample code will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string dirA = @"C:\";
string dirB = @"D:\";

string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirA);

foreach (string s in files) {
    if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(s).equals("bak")) {
        System.IO.File.Copy(s, System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message saying don't have access or like that for the line: System.IO.File.Copy(s, System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName), true);. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Because you dont'have permissions to copy files in the destination folder. What's your destination folder? Can you copy file in that folder using the operating system tools= (eg. explorer)

Comment: yes,certainly....I just give the directory path,not even a single folder.I think I need to make some property changed or something like that,but can't exactly figure it out.

Comment: Directory.GetFiles() will retrieve hidden and system files like recycling bin and pag files...  you can loop through each file using FileInfo instead of File and use if((fiFrom.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)